# Return value of "checked" from change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I declared a variable and want to pass the status of the checkbox to the `dhcp_addr` variable and set it to 1 when the checkbox is checked and 0 when its unchecked. Need some help in returning a value to the variable.

```
var dhcp_addr = $('#dhcp').change(function () {
  if(dhcp.checked) {
    console.log("checked");
  } else {
    console.log("unchecked");
  }
});
```

Comment: So just change `dhcp_addr` within the function? Like, `dhcp_addr = dhcp.checked;` Or if you need 1/0, `dhcp_addr = dhcp.checked ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 7):

You can't "return" it from the function because a change could happen at any time. Instead, you can reassign the value when a change occurs.

```
var dhcp_addr;
$('#dhcp').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    dhcp_addr = 1;
  } else {
    dhcp_addr = 0;
  }
});
```

Although, if you're using `1` and `0` for `true` and `false` values, I'd suggest using those values more directly.

```
dhcp_addr = this.checked;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest I came up with:

```
var dhcp_addr;

$("#dhcp").change(function () {
  dhcp_addr = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it using this code

```
var dhcp_addr;
$('#dhcp').change(function() {
 dhcp_addr = +this.checked;
});
```

So, `this.checked` is boolean and `+true` converts to number (1), `+false` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet code below :

```js
var dhcp_addr = $('#dhcp').change(function(){
  alert ( $('#dhcp').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="dhcp" id="dhcp" value="on" />Check <br />
```

Comment: Why are you using `$('#dhcp').is(':checked')`? It's not nearly as efficient as `this.checked`.

Comment: Completly agree with you. it should be 
`var dhcp_addr = $('#dhcp').change(function(){
      alert ( $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 );
    });`